# How to make an image radius in a collection view?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, radius

I would like to make a radius for my collection view to make the pictures a little more round. I have tried adding in the `viewdidload()` function the following:

```
mine.photo.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

`mine` is another class that I have with the IBOutlet `photo: UIImageView!`.

What I have to make my collection view neat are the following functions:

```
extension DiscoverViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 15
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        //dude.photo.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width / 2 - 2.5, height: collectionView.frame.size.width / 1.5 - 1 )

    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The round you need should be inside the cell class

```
class CellColl:UICollectionViewCell {
 @IBOutlet weak var photo: UIImageView!
   override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
      self.photo.layer.cornerRadius = 10
      self.photo.clipsToBounds = true
   }
}
```

Comment: add `clipsToBounds ` ??

Comment: still nothing happened

Comment: you mean you see the photo unrounded ?? can you share some related code like cellForItemAt and the cell class